# Multiple post requests for same form

Tags: php, forms

I have a form as:`<form action="test.php" method="post" name="testForm">`

And I have validations of image upload in another file "upload.php" which has some code as:

```
if (in_array($_FILES['myfile']['type'], $types)) {
if(filesize($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']) < $max_size) {
   $destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."images".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

So is there any way by which I can call the upload.php file without altering test.php file from form action attribute and perform my image upload validations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can alter the HTML code of your form, you could post to upload.php instead of test.php and then repost from upload.php to test.php (using CURL, for example)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what finally helped me.

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
include('upload.php');

            OR
```

by using copy of the function into test.php

Comment: The problem is how to do it without editing/accessing test.php.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, it would actually be better to use a jquery function which would submit the form to upload.php and then to test.php.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right there are many ways. I recommend reading a bit in the manual:

- [`include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
- [`functions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).
- [`class`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)
- [`filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php)

Comment: What I want basically is to call upload.php before the form is submitted in the same way as test.php is called on submitting the form.
By "In the same way" I mean it should also have access to all the form inputs.